# Code based on Barcelona city Timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code trying to get Barcelona city hour to show me a specific background and image too (based on the hour of the day) but seems to be that's not working.

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var now = new Date();
var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset();
var barcelona = new Date(now + (offset + 2*60)*60*1000);
var n = barcelona.getHours();

//1-2am if (n > 23 || n < 2) {
document.write('<body bgcolor="#2e3348" text="#FFFFFF">');
$("img#photo1").attr("src","images/head5.png");
}

//2-3am if (n > 24 || n < 4) {
document.write('<body bgcolor="#2e3348" text="#FFFFFF">');
$("img#photo1").attr("src","images/head4.png");
}

// and so go on - all the hours
```

And This is my HTML code

```
<div class="Center-child-div">
    <div class="child-div">
        <img src="" id="photo1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Any explanation why's not changing the background, is not showing the respective .png image? possible solution? thanks

Comment: What does the console log say?

Comment: `document.write('<body bgcolor="#2e3348" text="#FFFFFF">');` OMG please don't do that. Use this: `$("body").css({"background-color": "#2E3348", "color": "#FFF"});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `&&` operator instead of `||`. Also pay more attention to the `if` conditions:

```
var now = new Date(),
    offset = now.getTimezoneOffset(),
    barcelona = new Date(now + (offset + 2*60)*60*1000),
    n = barcelona.getHours();

// 1-2am 
if (n > 24 && n < 3) {
      $('body').css({
          'background-color': '#2e3348',
          'color': '#fff'
      });
      $("img#photo1").attr("src","images/head5.png");
} else
// 2-3am 
if (n > 1 && n < 4) {
      $('body').css({
          'background-color': '#2e3348',
          'color': '#fff'
      });
    $("img#photo1").attr("src","images/head4.png");
} else
// ......... if
```

Comment: Thanks @Matei Mihai but when I run the full code with this corrections still showing me a plain white background (the browser) without any image or any background:

Comment: In your html page you must have the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. The problem was that you had too many closing brackets. Next time, you can just open your console log, and it will give you any Javascript errors that are occurring. If Javscript encounter into an error, it will stop running at that point and any code after said point will not run.

This is the code that I used and had it work.

```
var now = new Date();
var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset();
var barcelona = new Date(now + (offset + 2*60)*60*1000);
var n = barcelona.getHours();

//1-2am if (n > 23 || n < 2) {
document.write('<body bgcolor="#2e3348" text="#FFFFFF">');
$("img#photo1").attr("src","images/head5.png");


//2-3am if (n > 24 || n < 4) {
document.write('<body bgcolor="#2e3348" text="#FFFFFF">');
$("img#photo1").attr("src","images/head4.png");
```

Also, I'm not sure if you include jQuery somewhere, but you can't use the `$` reference without it.

Comment: Seems to be that is not working neither:( @noahdotgansallo